# Vertical alignment of a table cell with rule

Tags: tables

My Problem: I try to fix the cell height with \rule{}{} ... The problem is that the vertical alignment in the cells of the first column should be centered. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
  \newcommand*\xbar[1]{%
 \hbox{%
\vbox{%
  \hrule height 0.5pt % The actual bar
  \kern0.5ex%         % Distance between bar and symbol
  \hbox{%
    \kern-0.1em%      % Shortening on the left side
    \ensuremath{#1}%
    \kern-0.1em%      % Shortening on the right side
    }%
   }%
  }%
   } 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Zusammenfassung: t-Test für den Parameter $\beta_0$}
  \framesubtitle{}  
 \begin{center}
 \scriptsize
   \begin{tabular}{|C{2.4cm}|C{8cm}|}\hline
  \rule{0pt}{25pt}Anwendungs-voraussetzungen & exakt: $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot x_i+u_i\quad\text{mit}\quad u_i\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ für $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\sigma^2$ unbekannt, $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ deterministisch und bekannt, Realisation $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ beobachtet\\\hline
    \rule{0pt}{15pt}Hypothesen & $H_0:\beta_0=\beta_0^0\quad\text{gegen}\quad H_1:\beta_0\neq\beta_0^0$ \\\hline
   \rule{0pt}{30pt}Teststatistik & $t=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_0-\beta_0^0}{\widehat{\sigma}_{\widehat{\beta}_0}}$\\\hline
   \rule{0pt}{15pt}Verteilung ($H_0$) & $t$ für $\beta_0=\beta_0^0$ $t(n-2)$-verteilt \\\hline
   \rule{0pt}{30pt}Benötigte Größen & $\widehat{\beta}_1=\frac{s_{xy}}{s_x^2}$, $\widehat{\beta}_0=\xbar{y}-\widehat{\beta}_1\cdot\xbar{x}$, $\widehat{\sigma}_{\widehat{\beta}_0}=\sqrt{\frac{s_y^2-\widehat{\beta}_1^2\cdot s_x^2}{(n-2)\cdot s_x^2}\cdot\xbar{x^2}}$ \\\hline
   \rule{0pt}{15pt}Kritischer Bereich & $(-\infty,-t_{1-\alpha/2}(n-2))\cup(t_{1-\alpha/2}(n-2),+\infty)$ 
 \\\hline  
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid off the `\rule{...}{...}` statements at the beginning of each row and include `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` to make the table taller

```
 \documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},10pt]{beamer}
 \usepackage{array}
 \newcommand{\xbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}

 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
 \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
 \newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Zusammenfassung: t-Test für den Parameter $\beta_0$}
   \framesubtitle{}    
   \begin{center}
     \scriptsize
     \begin{tabular}{|C{2.4cm}|C{8cm}|N}\hline
       Anwendungs-voraussetzungen & exakt: $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot x_i+u_i\quad\text{mit}\quad u_i\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ für $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\sigma^2$ unbekannt, $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ deterministisch und bekannt, Realisation $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ beobachtet&\\[25pt]\hline
       Hypothesen & $H_0:\beta_0=\beta_0^0\quad\text{gegen}\quad H_1:\beta_0\neq\beta_0^0$ &\\[25pt]\hline
       Teststatistik & $t=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_0-\beta_0^0}{\widehat{\sigma}_{\widehat{\beta}_0}}$&\\[25pt]\hline
       Verteilung ($H_0$) & $t$ für $\beta_0=\beta_0^0$ $t(n-2)$-verteilt &\\[25pt]\hline
       Benötigte Größen & $\widehat{\beta}_1=\frac{s_{xy}}{s_x^2}$, $\widehat{\beta}_0=\xbar{y}-\widehat{\beta}_1\cdot\xbar{x}$, $\widehat{\sigma}_{\widehat{\beta}_0}=\sqrt{\frac{s_y^2-\widehat{\beta}_1^2\cdot s_x^2}{(n-2)\cdot s_x^2}\cdot\xbar{x^2}}$ &\\[25pt]\hline
       Kritischer Bereich & $(-\infty,-t_{1-\alpha/2}(n-2))\cup(t_{1-\alpha/2}(n-2),+\infty)$ &\\[25pt]\hline  
     \end{tabular}
   \end{center}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already thought about that oportunity. But

Comment: first: there is no vertical centered alignment second: there should be more space between the rows

Comment: @Eric Increase `X` in `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{X}`

Comment: But the Text is not vertically centered too

Comment: In my first solution with the \rule{}{} at least the right column is verticale centered. The only task is to get the left one veerticale centered

Comment: @Eric I updated my answer